# Timestamp from String PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a ridiculous string provided by data that isn't adjustable and I need to convert it to a timestamp in a consistent manner.

`5162016`

sometimes 2 digit month, sometimes leading zeros sometimes not.

I tried using `DateTime`

```
$time = \DateTime::createFromFormat("njY", "5162016");
$timestamp = $time->getTimestamp();
```

I tried both `njY` and `mdY` but both return a timestamp that converts to `05/01/0020`

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Looked at http://php.net/strtotime?

Comment: Perhaps you could check the string length. But it would be impossible to differentiate 1122016 between 12 January and 2 November unless the day portion consistently has a leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your data, so that the month will be always with a leading zero.

```
$normalizedDate = str_pad("5162016", 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$time = \DateTime::createFromFormat("mdY", $normalizedDate);
$timestamp = $time->getTimestamp();
```

This **only** works if the Day of the month is always a 2 digits with leading zeros.

Comment: Isn't clear if there is a leading zero for the day portion. Unless there is, this cannot be used reliably.

Comment: So, both months and days can or cannot have leading zero? one time just month, another just day, some time both? then there's no way to distinguish them

Comment: Perhaps a combination? Remove the last 4 since that's the only reliable section. Then count the remaining characters. 2 and 4 should be reliable knowing we have either both 2 digit or both 1 digit. 3 on the other hand ... I would think perhaps if the first digit is not 0 or 1, then we have a single digit month, and can pad that with 0. Otherwise we have a 2 digit month and the day is the single.  Is something like this possible?